# Definir a class de um elemento li criado em tempo de execução

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-3

Abaixo tenho uma lista estilizada com o `bootstrap` (definindo a class de `ul` e `li`)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="bootstrap-3.3.6-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Add itens a lista</title>
</head>
<body>
    <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item">item 1</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">item 2</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">item 3</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">item 4</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">item 5</li>
    </ul>

</body>
</html>
```

A página fica desta forma:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém, não preciso de uma lista estática, e sim uma lista que será adicionado itens ao clicar em um botão. Até o momento tenho o código abaixo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="bootstrap-3.3.6-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Add itens a lista</title>
    <script>
        function addItem() {
            var li = document.createElement("li");
            /* Aqui deveria ser atribuída a class list-group-li
             * ao elemento li que acabou de ser criado
             * para que o mesmo apresente o design da class
             */
            li.class = "list-group-item";
             /* Porém acredito que a sintaxe esteja errada */
            li.innerHTML = "item n";
            var ul = document.getElementById("lista");
            ul.appendChild(li);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <ul class="list-group" id="lista">
    <!--Aqui será inserido 1 item li ao clicar no botão input_add-->
    </ul>

    <form>
        <input type=button id=input_add 
            value="Add item a lista" onclick="addItem()">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

O recurso de adicionar um item `li` na lista funciona corretamente, porém não consigo definir uma class para ele, class `list-group-item`. O resultado então, fica da seguinte forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Preciso de que meu li adicionado pelo código javascript tenha o mesmo design da primeira imagem. Alguma sugestão? Esta lógica de atribuir a class a um elemento já criado está correta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu código está praticamente certo, só o nome da propriedade que deve ser usada que está errada, em vez de `class` deve usar a `className`

```
li.className = "list-group-item";
```